# AutoMapper binding issues

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I am having trouble with AutoMapper not mapping to and from my ViewModels correctly. My primary model has a complex property named Contact of type Contact, i then have some fields on my ViewModel named Contact[PropertyName] an example of which is ContactFirst_Name.

Which seems to be correct as far as the documentation examples i can find say, i am essentially trying to flatten/unflatten the model but its not working. I did find a "fix" in another thread on stack overflow which meant i added the following line

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.RecognizePrefixes("Contact"));
```

to my mappings which then results in successful two way binding. This just seems wrong to me and has my thinking i am misunderstanding the way the default trappings work?

Am i?

ViewModel

```
    public class EmployeeViewModel : MVViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    public ContactTitleViewModel ContactTitle { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string ContactFirst_Name { get; set; }
    public string ContactMiddle_Names { get; set; }
    public string ContactLast_Name { get; set; }
    public string ContactEmail_Address { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }

    [TableFields("Name")]
    public List<EmployeeTrainingViewModel> Training { get; set; }
}
```

Minimal SQL Models

```
    public class Employee : ISQLObject
{
    public Contact Contact { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public virtual List<EmployeeTraining> Training { get; set; }

}

public class Contact : ISQLObject
    {
        public ContactTitle Title { get; set; }
        public string First_Name { get; set; }
        public string Middle_Names { get; set; }
        public string Last_Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Any chance you could post a minimal listing of your viewmodel and model so that we can see the properties you are trying to map.  Also post any code you are using to setup AutoMapper

Comment: I have done this now for all three models.

Comment: Issue seems to be caused by the `_`.  If you use `FirstName` and `ContactFirstName` instead it seems to work ok

Comment: Ah so if i just remove all of my underscores model wide i should get the default behaviour i was expecting?

Comment: Yes, or changing the expected naming convention for the configuration appears to work: `cfg.SourceMemberNamingConvention = new LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention();`

Comment: This does indeed seem to have solved my problem!